# Fix UV showing seams in all modes except texture paint

Tags: uv, texture-painting

Was following CGBoost's tutorial on texture painting an apple until I got to a hiccup where when in any mode that isn't texture paint, my object ends up showing the seams that I marked earlier. I followed the unwrapping process pretty much all the way, but struggled a little with texture painting.

After a few tries, I liked the result but when I moved onto shading mode, the visible seams from earlier showed clearly from far away. From up close, they're not there at all. It didn't look like I missed any spots either.

I was told this might have something to do with fake users? But I didn't really understand how to fix it. I ended up deleting all the textures I made and started from scratch but it was still there.

With the knife and blade, however, I had 0 issues. It was just with the apple.

Any tips? I really wanna move forward with this tutorial.

visible blue seams from afar: [image: https://i.imgur.com/fGIM3mE.png]

up-close: [image]

Comment: Try to make bigger margin on your texture.

Comment: maybe pack the image (File > External Data > Pack All Into Blend) and share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @FFeller Sure, I'll try this when I get home later and share results

Comment: @moonboots Hopefully I did this correctly! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6709" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6709/)

Comment: Your file makes my Blender version crash, I hope someone will help you

Comment: @moonboots Yikes, sorry to hear. Thank you for trying anyway!